# Putting 'noexcept' on possible UB

Tags: c++, function, undefined-behavior, noexcept

```
struct A {
  int* a_ptr;
};

struct B {
  A* b_ptr;
};


struct C {  // iterator
  B* c_ptr;

  //...

  int& f() noexcept(?) {  // provides some access if 'C' is valid
    return c_ptr->b_ptr->a_ptr;
  }
};
```

Imagine: `C` is some custom iterator, which is always valid until its container is deleted. Otherwise, calling `C::f` will result in `UB`. We trust the user that he will never try to create `C`, to delete its container and then to call `C::f` (we will warn him that it is a bad practice).

So, the question is whether *I can put `noexcept(true)` on `f`* or *not* from the code-writing-ethics point of view? I am looking for some reasoning for any of the decisions.

Comment: Your question is built on the assumption that undefined behavior results in an ordinary thrown exception. This assumption is not true.

Comment: C++ is built on the assumption that undefined behavior will never occur (or to put it another way, if undefined behavior *does* occur, it's the programmer's fault and the language has no responsibilities to behave one way or the other).  Given that, I wouldn't worry about what happens in the face of UB, since nobody else worries about it either (other than to say "don't do that")

Comment: By my question I mean whether ordinary UB *is better* that an emergency program shutdown (UB from noexcept function)

Comment: You're overthinking this. Undefined behavior means that the C++ language definition does not tell you what the program will do. That's all. There are no degrees of undefined behavior. If your design ensures that, with correct usage, calling `C::f` will never thrown an exception, then marking it `noexcept(true)` may be appropriate ("may be" because I don't like exception specifiers). There's nothing in the code you've shown that throws an exception, so `noexcept(true)` seems appropriate.

Comment: Now I've heard what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Upvoting because it's an entirely fair question for a (relative) novice to ask

Comment: @PaulSanders makes a good point that I overlooked. Yes, bad code sometimes generates mysterious "exceptions", but there's nothing you can do about that. `noexcept` is about exceptions that your code throws, with `throw my_exception`. There are no `throw` statements in your code, so `noexcept` is appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker Just in case you don't know, we Windows folks have the luxury of 'Structured Exception Handling'.  Nothing to do with C++ exceptions, this can catch (and recover from), for example, `* (int *) 0 = 0;`.

Comment: @PaulSanders -- yes, Windows programmers have the "luxury" of being able to maintain control of a program whose data is thoroughly corrupted and imagining that they can do something sensible with nonsense. <g>

Comment: Maybe it helps to say it the other way around - if your program is causing UB, then *omitting* `noexcept` will not make the situation any better.

Comment: UB does not mean "throws an exception when UB occurs".  UB does not mean "emergency program shutdown when UB occurs".  A `throw` out of a `noexcept` function is not UB, it's well-defined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker I use it to email a crash dump back to base.  It's not the only way, maybe not even the best way, but it is not without merit and has helped me diagnose *a lot* of problems in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ is built on the assumption that undefined behavior will never occur

> There are no degrees of undefined behavior

> `noexcept` is about exceptions that **your** code throws, with `throw my_exception`

So, if a function never throws exceptions it is appropriate to put on `noexcept(true)` even if it can invoke `UB` under incorrect usage.

However... *(check commentaries)*

Comment: I changed the last sentence to change the emphasis. Feel free to roll back the change if you don't like it. +1.

Comment: Note that when you put `noexcept`, you're blocking a possibility to detect UB by making an explicit check and throwing an exception (which you might want to do in a debug build). For this reason, some standard library functions, which seem to be `noexcept`, are not marked as such. For example, `std::vector::operator[]`.

Comment: @Evg thank you! I think this is a great reason. But. What do you mean by *blocking a detection of UB*? Can you write a short program example, please?

Comment: @MilkyWay Suppose you standardize `reference operator[](size_t) noexcept` signature for `std::vector::operator[]`. Then no implementation will be able to do something like "#ifndef NDEBUG if (index >= size()) throw ...; #endif` because throwing from `noexcept` function will lead to immediate process termination.

Comment: Interestingly, while looking for a good reference, I found [this one](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1656r2.html), which reads *It is a common misconception that the policy supports standard library implementations that wish to diagnose contract violations by throwing exceptions. No known implementation actually wants this.* I don't whether this is actually true or not, but this paper is definitely worth reading anyway.